# System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: 'Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression '((BookingID = ?) - DB.DBDA.UpdateCommand

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, datagridview

I have a DataGridView and when I try to save any alterations made, I receive the error in the title.

The full error code contains more missing operators

> (System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: 'Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression '((BookingID = ?) AND ((? = 1 AND RoomType IS NULL) OR (RoomType = ?)) AND ((? = 1 AND Check-In IS NULL) OR (Check-In = ?)) AND ((? = 1 AND Checkout IS NULL) OR (Checkout = ?)) AND ((? = 1 AND NoNights IS NULL) OR (NoNights = ?)) AND ((? = 1 AND Adults IS '.')

The code in question can be viewed below:

```vb
    Private Sub frmViewEditBookings_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        'Execute query and populate DGV
        DB.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM tblRoomBookings ORDER BY BookingID ASC")

        'Perform subroutine LoadGrid
        LoadGrid()

        'Disable Save Button
        btnSave.Enabled = False
    End Sub

    'Load and refresh DGV
    Private Sub LoadGrid()
        'If data is returned populate DGV and build update command
        If DB.RecordCount > 0 Then
            dgvBookings.DataSource = DB.DS.Tables(0)
            dgvBookings.Rows(0).Selected = True
            DB.DBDA.UpdateCommand = New OleDb.OleDbCommandBuilder(DB.DBDA).GetUpdateCommand
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnSave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click
        'Save changes to database
        DB.DBDA.Update(DB.DS)

        'Perform subroutine LoadGrid 
        LoadGrid()

        'Disable btnSave
        btnSave.Enabled = False
    End Sub

    Private Sub dgvBookings_CellValueChanged(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles dgvBookings.CellValueChanged
        'Enable btnSave 
        btnSave.Enabled = True
    End Sub

    Private Sub dgvBookings_RowsRemoved(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewRowsRemovedEventArgs) Handles dgvBookings.RowsRemoved
        'Enable btnSave
        btnSave.Enabled = True
    End Sub
```

Thank you for your time :)

Comment: Could you update the question to add the value of `DB.DBDA.UpdateCommand`, please?

Comment: @AndrewMorton I have added it to the title if that's what you meant

Comment: The problem is the column name `Check-In`. How do you build your UpdateCommand?

Comment: @Steeeve Thank you, I've changed it to "CheckIn". I do not know how the UpdateCommand is built, sorry

Comment: This line is pointless: `DB.DBDA.UpdateCommand = New OleDb.OleDbCommandBuilder(DB.DBDA).GetUpdateCommand`. There is no need or point to calling `GetUpdateCommand` unless you're going to somehow modify the command it returns, e.g. enrol it in a transaction. Just create a command builder and call `Update` on your data adapter. It will use the generated commands automatically.

Comment: @jmcilhinney I removed ```DB.DBDA.UpdateCommand = New OleDb.OleDbCommandBuilder(DB.DBDA).GetUpdateCommand``` and now I get the error: 
```System.InvalidOperationException: 'Update requires a valid UpdateCommand” when passed DataRow collection with modified rows.'``` on the line ```DB.DBDA.Update(DB.DS)```

Comment: The thing I failed to notice is that you are creating the command builder on that line as well. You do need to create the command builder but you don't need to call GetUpdateCommand and assign the result anywhere. Just create the command builder in the same place and at the same time as the data adapter. I really don't like data access layers like the one you're using but if that's what you have, you can still use it better.

Answer (score 0):

When you use a command builder, what it generates is based on the `SelectCommand` of the data adapter. If you use `SELECT *` in your query, the command builder will just use each column name as is. This means that any column names that are keywords or contain spaces or other special characters will cause a syntax error.

If you write out your column list explicitly then you would have to escape such column names, e.g. `SELECT [Check-In], ...`. The command builder would then follow your lead and escape the names too. If you want to tell the command builder to escape the column names without having to write out the full column list yourself, the solution is to set its `QuotePrefix` and `QuoteSuffix` properties:

```vb
Dim builder As New OleDbCommandBuilder(adapter) With {.QuotePrefix = "[", .QuoteSuffix = "]"}
```

That said, it really is better to just avoid such column names in the first place.